# Spring-Roo: How to retrieve component instance dinamically by name or id?

Tags: java, osgi, spring-roo

I have a class annotated with @Component and @Service. The usual way of getting the instance of this class from the beans container is using @Reference:

```
@Reference private MyClass myclass;
```

How could I retrieve the instance using a string key as we do with ApplicationContext in Spring Web applications? I've tried with ComponentContext.locateService but I don't know if this is correct nor which key value I have to use.

```
MyClass myclass = (MyClass)context.locateService("????"); //Which is the way?
```

---

I edit my question, I'll try to explain better.
I have a class like this:

```
@Component
@Service
class MySvcImpl implements MySvc { ... }
```

injected this way:

```
class Main {
   @Reference private MySvc svc;

   void method1(){
       svc.doXXX();
   }
}
```

In this case I have a single class. I'd want to have a bunch of component subclasses (MySvcSubX) so that I can use any of them according to a parameter. Allegedly, I'd not need the @Reference line anymore.

```
@Component
@Service
class MySvcSub1Impl extends MySvcImpl implements MySvc { ...}    
//The same with MySvcSub2Impl, 3, and so forth
```

And then in my Main class:

```
void method1(String key){
    MySvc svc = callToLocateBeanById(key);
}
```

I should not need to add a reference for each of the subclasses to be able to locate them by their name.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:mySpringConfig.xml");
MyClass myClassBean =  (MyClass) context.getBean("myClass");
```

Comment: if i have understand this question correctly, it's related to osgi declarated-services, not spring. But i don't know why there is a spring-roo tag :-)

Comment: The spring-roo tag is because I'm developing an addon. Spring Roo addons use OSGi features and Roo shell installs them using the osgi command.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a `@Component` with a property :

```
@Component(property="type=xxx")
public class MyComponent implements MySvc {

}
```

and then query the osgi registry with a filter on this property :

```
BundleContext bc = ..;
Collection<ServiceReference<MySvc>> ref = bc.getServiceReferences(MySvc.class, "(type=xxx)")
// check cardinality, etc
MySvc svc = bc.getService(ref);
// use svc
bc.ungetService(ref);
```

If you know the key you are looking for at compile time (or though some configuration), you can inject a reference with a target :

```
@Reference(target = "(type=xxx)")
private MySvc component;
```

**Old answer**

You should use the name of the reference. This name can be specified in `@Reference`, but the default is generated from the name of the property, or the bind/unbind method (see the javadoc for this annotation)

In your example, it should be :

```
MyClass myclass = (MyClass)context.locateService("myClass");
```

If you're not sure, you can look at the generated xml from your component, you'll see the generated name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try, but I'm not sure that It is what I want. I've extended my question text explaining this.

Comment: The added question at the end doesn't make any sense to me. Can you try to explain it differently?

Comment: Hi Jerémie, your approach works, but as I say, I think it's not exactly what I want. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sounds great. I'll try and tell you. Thanks!